# html table bottom alignment issue

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<style type="text/css">
.message-view-value-td {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
</style>
<table width="600">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="15%" class="message-view-label">
    <xsl:text>Really long text here that will wrap:</xsl:text>
</td>

<td class="message-view-value-td" width="35%">
    value1
</td>

<td valign="top" width="15%" class="message-view-label">
    <xsl:text>Short_Label:</xsl:text>
</td>

<td class="message-view-value-td" width="35%">
    value2
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Without creating two inner tables for each label/value, is it possible to vertical align "value2" with "Short_Label" independently from "value1" alignment? So that each value aligns at the base level of it's corresponding label.

It should look like:

```
Really long                     Short_Label:        Value2
text here 
that will
wrap:               Value1   

Another long                    Another_label:      Value4
text value:         Value3
```

Thanks!

UPDATE-1: even if I create inner tables, I get into another issue: Value1 and Value3 should be left-aligned to each-other. Inner tables solve the first issue but they break this left-alignment of the values. 
Now I really don't know any solution to solve it :) Hope someone could shed some light here.

UPDATE-2: is this even possible with a CSS-based solution?

Comment: `<tables>` are fine if it is tabular data  (which it looks like it _might_ be) but `valign` and `width` have been deprecated for a while. The CSS equivalents are much preferred.

Comment: Why are you using a table-based layout? If possible, a pure CSS solution may be better.

Comment: I have a big html that is all using tables, it would take too much time to refactor.

Comment: what do you mean by base level? Also, I think you mean 'is it possible to vertical align "value2" with "Short_Label" independently from "value1" alignment'?

Comment: my mistake, corrected. The base level means that I want the first label to wrap and it's value to be aligned bottom, while the second label which can't wrap to have it's value aligned relatively from it, on the same line. I'll give an example of how it should look.

Comment: This is horrid, but you set column one and two to `vertical-align:bottom`; and column three to `vertical-align:top`. This is a very sloppy solution.

Comment: @MetalFrog: if the second field would wrap as well, this wouldn't work

Comment: @danleadgy As I said, this is a sloppy solution to a sloppy problem. I'm reasonably confident that this doesn't need to be a table. Besides, your question doesn't say anything about accommodating more than one long label.

Comment: @MetalFrog: I understand you perfectly, it's just that the solution you gave was the first I thought of but then when both fields wrap, I had issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is "**No**," it cannot be done. If you can reconfigure your html some, then you have a chance of getting what you want while keeping it in a single table.

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5U3yc/16/.

It uses `span` around your label and value *within* a single table cell to get your desired effect.

Comment: Thank you, @ScottS! A very interesting approach. And yes, it is possible to reconfigure the html to such a degree. If the left-align of the values between different tables is preserved, then this is the ideal solution. It remains an interesting exercise to make a CSS-only solution - but that is not really required. So thanks a lot once more!